# Find when tar find n matches using wildcards

Tags: wildcard, tar

I'm trying to extract from a huge tar file some files from a list that are using wildcards. I'm using a loop to read the list but passing from one element in the list to the next one is taking too long, I'm guessing because is trying to match the element through the whole tar file. I want that after 2 matches for any element, the loop continues with the next one.

```
while read line;do
 tar --wildcards  -xzvf file.tar.gz "$line"
done <$file
```

And one line looks like this

`dataset/0113947.*`

Answer (score 1):

I went aggresive and kill the tar process as soon as it finds two files. Here is my solution

```
file=list.txt
while read line;do
 tar --wildcards --checkpoint=10000 --checkpoint-action=exec='sh stop.sh dummy.txt 1' -xzvf ny_file.tar.gz "$line" > dummy.txt
done <$file
```

where stop.sh checks if dummy.txt has more than two lines and kill the process.

```
n=$(wc -l < $1)
if [ $n -gt 1 ];then
 kill $(ps aux|grep "[t]ar --wildcards*" |  cut -d " " -f 4)
fi
```

I had to use cut to recover the ID process because the single quotes for awk were troubling